# Constrained least-square regression - Matlab or R

Tags: r, matlab, linear-regression

I'm doing a least-square regression on some data, the function has the form

```
y ~ a + b*x
```

and I want the regression line to pass through a specific point P(x,y) (which is not the origin).
How can I do that?

I'm using the lm command in R and the basic fitting GUI in Matlab.
I think that I could use the constrOptim command (in R) or translate the origin into the point P, but I'm wondering if there's a specific command to do that.

I only need the solution for one of these programs, then I can use the coefficients in the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just center the data appropriately and force the regression through the 'origin':

```
lm(y ~ I(x-x0)-1, offset=rep(y0,nrow(dat)) data=dat)
```

You might then need to adjust the intercept coefficient accordingly.

**edited**: `offset` needs to be a vector of the correct length.  Another way to do this would be:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10,mean=1:10,sd=0.1))
x0 <- 3
y0 <- 3
(lm1 <- lm(y ~ I(x-x0)-1, offset=y0, data=data.frame(d,y0)))
```

This gives a slope of 1.005.  The intercept would be `coef(lm1)*(-y0/x0)`, I think.

Comment: I've tried as you say with
`x0 <- 3.15
y0 <-283.56
regression <- lm(y ~ I(x-x0)-1, offset=y0)`
(I think that `data = dat` is not necessary in this case) but I have this error : 
`Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ I(x - x0) - 1,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(offset)')`. I don't understand why..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've asked how _offset_ works in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16920628/2271092).

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing the question! Both of the solutions you've proposed work.