# How do I 'set' the linear regression slope in R?

Tags: r

Based on literature species richness = animal weight ^ -0.75. I did a linear regression using my data and I got a pretty close result, i.e. y = -0.57 x + 4.63. However, I also want to check how a linear regression line with a slope = -0.75 is. Can I use my dataset, and sort of 'set' the slope (x) to equal -0.75 when I call the summary command in R?

My code is:

```
    x = c(2.1,2.3,2.5,2.7,2.9,3.1,3.3,3.5,3.7,3.9,4.1,4.3,4.5,4.7,4.9,5.1,5.3,5.5,5.7,
  5.9,6.1,6.3,6.5,6.7,6.9,7.1,7.3,7.5,7.7,7.9)

    y = c(3.05, 2.95, 2.97, 2.98, 2.84, 2.85, 2.83, 2.71, 2.64, 2.62, 2.58, 2.37, 2.26, 2.17, 2.00, 1.88, 1.75, 1.62, 1.36, 1.30, 1.08, 1.20, 0.90, 0.30, 0.70, 0.30, 0.48, 0.00, 0.30, 0.00)

    fit = lm(y ~ x)

    coef(fit)

    (Intercept)           x 
    4.6302377  -0.5727809
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: take logs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset()` function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920628/use-of-offset-in-lm-regression-r).

Comment: That's not how you add an offset